# How to convert mysql query filtered by TIME() function to laravel query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

So far this is the MySQL query and it works perfectly. It filters records by matching passed value to TIME(fecha_hora):

```
 select nombre_departamento, categoria_respuesta, count(valor_evaluacion) from 
       detalle_evaluaciones JOIN departamentos ON departamentos.id = 
       detalle_evaluaciones.departamentos_id JOIN tipo_respuestas ON tipo_respuestas.id = detalle_evaluaciones.tipo_respuestas_id 
        where TIME(fecha_hora) = '06:13:00'

    group by nombre_departamento, categoria_respuesta ORDER BY `tipo_respuestas`.`id` desc
```

This is what I have tried:

```
$hora = $request->get('hora');
  $hora1 = date('H:i:s', strtotime("$hora"));
        $calif = DB::table ('detalle_evaluaciones')->select (DB::raw('departamentos.nombre_departamento,tipo_respuestas.categoria_respuesta,   detalle_evaluaciones.valor_evaluacion, COUNT(detalle_evaluaciones.valor_evaluacion) as cantidad'))
      ->join  ('departamentos','detalle_evaluaciones.departamentos_id','=','departamentos.id')
      ->join  ('tipo_respuestas','detalle_evaluaciones.tipo_respuestas_id','=','tipo_respuestas.id')
      ->whereRaw('(TIME(detalle_evaluaciones.fecha_hora)=?)',$hora1)

      ->groupby ('departamentos.nombre_departamento','tipo_respuestas.categoria_respuesta')

      ->orderby ('tipo_respuestas.id','DESC')
      ->paginate(10);
```

`$calif` will save all query data and return it and `$hora1` is getting input time and passing its value to query builder where clause. It is not working at all. fecha_hora is of datetime type and it has both the date and time.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use whereRaw ? You can use whereTime instead whereRaw. It is better way... For example:

```
->whereTime('detalle_evaluaciones.fecha_hora)', '=', $hora1);
```

Comment: Yes, didn't know about whereTime. Great. Marked yours as the answer